# Python spyder: changing a function in another file takes no effect

Tags: python, spyder

Using spyder 3.2.4 with python.

When I call i function (in another file) lets call it my_func() from my main script, it uses the "old version" of that function. Clarification:

If i change my_func and save that file, the new version of the function is used if called from my main script, BUT only if I run the entire main script.

If i just run the lines with my_func (using run cell or run selected lines) the OLD version of my_func (before the changes was mad) is used.

I though my_func had to be "reimported" (from myOtherFile import my_func), so I try to run those lines as well, but the old version of the function (not changed) is still used.

Did I misunderstand something or is this a really, really serious bug? If i close down spyder and restart it it works (it uses the new version of the function) but that's an unacceptable solution.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior has to do with how the (I)Python interpreter handles imports.

You can find a detailed explanation (with possible solutions) here: https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart

Short answer:
- either restart the kernel
- or use importlib.reload (https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)
- or use IPython's autoreload extension (http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html)

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not a bug, it's the way Python works. However, the normal behavior can be improved by making our IPython consoles to load the `%autoreload` IPython magic. With that change, after saving a file you'll immediately get the code on it reloaded in your console.

We'll do this in our **3.2.5** version (to be released on December 2017).